# Declaring variables to store data from previous IoT feed in MULE

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio, iot

Im starting working on Mule and im trying to make an app that will "predict" if it's going to rain and post it on twitter using IoT.

The app has an http connector that gets humidity feeds from a sensor, and here comes my question.

Is there anyway to store the humidity in some kind of variable so when a new feeds comes in I can compare both, the old and the new? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a spring bean with a scope of singleton. You can compare it to this object.

You can refer to this:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can save the HTTP result into a spring object or mule session. Though mule session is not recommended especially on large datas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object store spring object to persist the previous feed. Follow [this link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-object-stores) to leanr more about Mule Object Store.

You cannot use Mule Session Properties because they are available only through the same event scope, not all events received by the flow.

Hope it helps.

/T

Answer (score 0):

Mule Object Store is the perfect way to save small amount of data, but if it can go large might as well considering to save your data in a database/nosql servers. Since the value of IOT data is not the current data but the most important thing is its historical value for analytics.